# How to defer promising with status in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to find similar questions (hopefully I am right) so I decide to ask

I have a lot of deferred promise methods from my own services, something like this

```
function GetSomething(id) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(url + "/" + id)
            .success(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            })
            .error(function (err, status) {
                // I wish I won't need to do something like this
                if (status === 404)
                    deferred.reject("Not Found");
                else
                    deferred.reject(err);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
}
```

When I am calling this, I do

```
myService.getSomething(id).then ( 
    function(response) {
       // normal
    },

    function(err, status) {
       // HERE no more additional input parameter
    }
}
```

so, my question is, if I use deferred promise, how can I reject it with all additional parameter, such as "status", so I don't have to manually construct a "reason" for the reject method

I don't think it's a big deal, actually when I am typing this, I feel it's probably fine, so my service will handle the 404 and redirect to a specific page when it encounters such a status. Initially I was thinking to make all my services dumb, which simply returns the promise without any UI logic

Comment: You can do, `deferred.reject({error: err, status: status})`. And, you don't really need a `deferred` - see [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns)

Comment: ah, good read. Thanks!